# Calling a Gradle Task conditionally

Tags: gradle, conditional-statements, task, execute

Assume I have 2 tasks:

```
tasks.register('taskA') {
  // do something
}

tasks.register('taskB') {
  // do something else
}
```

for my gradle build, I only want to call task "build" and depending on a
condition, it should decide which other task to call:

```
tasks.register('build') {
    doLast {
        if (condition == true) {
            // tasks.named('taskA').execute {}
        } else {
            // tasks.named('taskB').execute {}
        }
    }
}
```

there is no such function as "execute", but whats the best practice in Gradle
to archive that behaviour ? I also read that one should avoid "dependsOn" if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sample shows that the `build` task is being created. Generally, this task is already created for you when you apply one of the provided Gradle plugins such as the [Java Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html). The [Base Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/base_plugin.html) is generally applied when applying a plugin Gradle provides. Some use cases you may apply the plugin manually. This answer assumes the Java plugin is applied, uses the [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html), and Gradle 8.

---

You can use a [task predicate](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:using_a_predicate) to conditionally execute tasks. The recommendation to avoid using `dependsOn` is because usually there is an idiomatic way to express your intent in Gradle. In this case, a task predicate is exactly what you need here. For example:

```
tasks {
    val taskA by registering {
        onlyIf("condition A is satisfied") {
            1 + 1 == 2
        }
        doLast {
            // task execution logic
        }
    }
    val taskB by registering {
        onlyIf("condition A is satisfied") {
            1 + 1 == 2
        }
        doLast {
            // ...
        }
    }
    build {
        dependsOn(taskA, taskB)
    }
}
```

Breaking this down:

1. Register the task as you did, but make use of the `onlyIf` predicate. Task will only execute if the predicate is satisfied.
2. Use `doLast { }` for your task execution logic. For more complex uses, consider creating a [custom task type](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html).
3. The built-in `build` task does not carry any meaningful semantics in Gradle, it is a "catch all" build everything task. So, it is fine to use `dependsOn` in this case.

Comment: Thank you Cisco for the good and short example + explanation! It works like expected ! The "build" task is indeed already there, as you mentioned. It's named different in my "real" code. Kind regards!